# Can one use an Apple TV if they do not have another device on which to create an "iTunes Store Account"?

Tags: itunes, apple-id, appletv

I am trying to setup an **Apple TV** for an elderly person with dementia so she can watch TV.
I have her Apple credentials, and I set it up so that I get the two-factor authentication codes on my iPhone.

However when I try to add channels/apps to her **Apple TV**, I get this fun error message:

[image]

She doesn't have other devices such as a phone or a computer (because of her condition, we have to do things for her). And my devices are paired with my personal Apple ID.

I tried logging in with her info on the Apple website, but haven't found a "Create iTunes Store Account" option on there.

**How can I create an "iTunes Store Account" for her so she can be able to watch TV? Can someone who only has an Apple TV use it?**

Comment: If you have a Mac, you can create a local user account for her on your Mac to complete this

Comment: You mean a guest account?

Comment: No, just a regular account - you can give it her name and any password you choose. She would never use it, but you can use it to do things like create an iTunes Store account for her

Comment: Oh ok I understand. And I wouldn’t be able to do that on a guest account ?

Comment: @Ezekiel can you make your comment an answer so I can accept it? I was able to do it on a guest account of my computer

Comment: why not just sign in with yours? you can then disable purchasing if you are concerned about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a Mac, you can make another account on the computer and use that account to sign in and create the iTunes Store account.

I recommend creating a regular non-administrator account for this person, and fully signing into iCloud as well, but (it seems like) a Guest account should also work.

The disadvantage to a Guest account being that you don't stay signed in if you ever need to adjust the account in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unfortunate reality of Apple's walled garden: they expect you to have a core computing device (iPhone, iPad, etc.) already before you get to use one of their devices like an Apple TV. Bless you though for helping an elderly person, there's not enough of that going on in this world.